# Replace quote in SQL Select

Tags: sql

I have a scenario in my vb.net project where users need to select a name from a combobox (or type a new name).

Names of course can have **'** as in **Tina O'Hara** which in the database would be stored as **Tina O''Hara**.

My combobox is populated from a sql select command. I have tried to use a **Replace** so that the names display correctly in the dropdown.

```
SqlStr = "SELECT Replace(ContactName, '''', ''') AS ddlText FROM tbl_Visits Where CustID = " & hd_CustID.value & " ORDER By ContactName"
PopulateCMBX(cmbx_ContactName, SqlStr, "Please Select")
```

***PopulateCMBX**... This gets a list of names from the supplied SqlStr and populates the combobox itemlist with a 'Please Select' as the first option.*

SqlStr is producing an error as there is not a matching set of **'** how do I fix this. Thanks

Comment: What does the error say exactly? And why have you stored the names in your DB with double apostrophes?

Comment: I can't store with single quote as this will not work e.g. Insert Into Tbl_Customer Value ('Tina O'Hara') so I have to insert as Tina O''Hara. Then whenever I display I do a .Replace("''", "'"). I can't use this to populate my combobox though

Comment: There is no necessity to store apostrophes doubled up. Inserting `Tina O''Hara` will store it with a single quote. Except if you are passing that string as a parameterised query, in which case you don't need to escape the apostrophe at all.

Comment: Is there a reason that you have chosen not to use parameterized queries? By separating the parameters from the rest of the query the issue of handling "special" characters goes away. It also avoids most common security problems with SQL injection.

Comment: Martin, HABO and Radu... I am one of these people who once he has found a way to do something he sticks with it... and so I tend to build queries using cocatanated strings or a stringbuilder. Any place where the user has had free rein on input I will subject to a function that will replace single quotes with double and check for SQLInjection. I am not familiar with parameterised queries so I'm off to search what they are now. Many thanks for point to another option.

Comment: @Mych - You must be double escaping if a single apostrophe ends up as 4 in the `INSERT` statement (and thus two in the stored DB) but yes just use parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referencing single quotes in MS-SQL, you need to escape each single quote (') with two single quotes ('').

If the name is stored in the database with two single quotes, such as (''), then when you do the replace you need to use four single quotes (''''). In addition to these, you need to enclose the string with single quotes.

What this means is that your replace should look like this:

```
SqlStr = "SELECT Replace(ContactName, '''''', '''') ...
```

The 2nd param in the replace has 6 single quotes: 4 to represent the two single quotes you are replacing, and 2 to make it a string. The 3rd param has 4 single quotes: 2 to represent a single escaped quote and two to make it a string.

Comment: Wonderful.... many thanks for your swift reply.. Not to others I had to add the Replace clause to the Order By section also. so my finished sql was....
"SELECT Replace(ContactName, '''''', '''') AS ddlText FROM tbl_Visits Where CustID = " & hd_CustID.value & " ORDER By Replace(ContactName, '''''', '''')"

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, maybe not the best solution but it works (check this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73c74/15)):

```
select Replace(Replace(ContactName, '''', '$&'),'$&$&','''') from tbl_Visits
```

Note that **$&** is like a key that should not affect the values ​​in your field, for example, could be a word: &&k&& or %%key%%, etc.
Back to clarify, it is not the best solution, but sometimes i've used.